# result of php rawurlencode() different on different server

Tags: php, forms, urlencode, url-encoding, rawurl

On a dedicated server:

```
$_POST['kannada']='ಕನ್ನಡ';
rawurlencode($_POST['kannada']);
```

gives

```
%26%233221%3B%26%233240%3B%26%233277%3B%26%233240%3B%26%233233%3B
```

On my local server:

```
$_POST['kannada']='ಕನ್ನಡ';
rawurlencode($_POST['kannada'])
```

gives

```
%E0%B2%95%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%A1
```

the expected result is which i am getting on local server. Why this different result? please tell me.

Ok. Below is the file i ran on different servers. you can check it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="kn">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<form name="submit" method="post">
<input type="text" name="kannada">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo $_POST['kannada']."<br/>";
    echo rawurlencode($_POST['kannada']);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've more than likely got a difference in the charset used between the two servers.

Comment: I´d guess one of the servers (i.e. PHP) is UTF-8, the other is not.

Comment: Hi. i actually ran same file on different server.

Comment: @KrishGowda exactly..?

Comment: yes. exactly same file.

Comment: @KrishGowda - That's not possible. `rawurlencode()` has nothing to do with HTML, it'll never generate HTML entities from scratch. Are you sure your test is not different, e.g, an HTML form?

Comment: @ZsoltSzilagy i don't understand what you mean? "UTF-8 PHP server"? what does that mean? can u please elaborate? and how do i check it? and the first one has linux operating system and local server is on windows operating system.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario i am pretty sure. i uploaded the same file to server and ran it.

Comment: Yes, you already said that, I'm asking whether the test file you upload contains the code you've posted here and not some variation of it (for instance, an HTML form where you type ಕನ್ನಡ and submit it).

Comment: i updated the post with the file which i am running on different servers. please check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

echo rawurldecode('%26%233221%3B%26%233240%3B%26%233277%3B%26%233240%3B%26%233233%3B') . PHP_EOL;
echo rawurldecode('%E0%B2%95%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%A1');
```

... prints:

```
&#3221;&#3240;&#3277;&#3240;&#3233;
ಕನ್ನಡ
```

Your two strings are simply different even though, when rendered in HTML context, they look the same.

---

**Edit #1:** It's actually possible to obtain HTML entities within your POST variables but that's a browser feature: if the user types some characters that are not supported by the document encoding inside an HTML form, the browser prefers to generate HTML entities instead of sending or dropping unsupported characters. But you do you need a browser; it won't happen if you fill `$_POST` manually from PHP.

---

**Edit #2:** As I was suspecting, the code you posted wasn't the actual code. Your input strings are not the same but you didn't notice because you are manipulating the form data as HTML:

```
echo $_POST['kannada']."<br/>";
```

... thus your HTML entities are being **rendered** as HTML. You need to do this:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['kannada'])."<br/>";
```

The rest is what I already said. Your page is not being interpreted as UTF-8. Make sure that:

1. Your editor is saving files as UTF-8
2. The web server is sending a correct `Content-Type` header. You can force it from PHP:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
   ```

Comment: yes. i prefer the second one because it will be rendered properly in urls.

Comment: It's actually more than a matter of preference. If you accept HTML from untrusted sources you might be open to XSS attacks unless you implement specially crafted security measures. If you only accept plain text everything's easier.

Comment: for now security is not an issue. it is a simple website. my client wants nice looking urls.

Comment: It's a good policy. That way you can charge the customer every time the site gets hacked. :)

Comment: you are right . the editor was not saving the file properly. i did this. File Save as > checked the option include unicode signature > then uploaded the file to server and ran it. i got the second type of encoding which i used to get locally.

Comment: Unicode signature (BOM) is not mandatory for UTF-8 and it often just creates problems. Saving as UTF-8 without BOM (not ANSI or Unicode or anything else) should be enough. The most likely reason is an incorrect `Content-Type` header, something you can verify with your browser's developer tools.

Comment: ok i will do it. it's just that my editor was not showing that encoding options. i saved using windows notepad. and THANK YOU soo much. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

First result is Unicode charset

```
mb_convert_encoding($unicode_content, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xkj-nyr

```
<?php
//UNICODE
$a = rawurldecode("%26%233221%3B%26%233240%3B%26%233277%3B%26%233240%3B%26%233233%3B");

//UTF-8
$b = rawurldecode("%E0%B2%95%E0%B2%A8%E0%B3%8D%E0%B2%A8%E0%B2%A1");

//Convert to utf-8
echo mb_convert_encoding($a, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
echo "\r\n";
echo $b;
```